# Animate jquery mobile collapsible with css

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

How to make jquery mobile collapsible content appear with animation using css transition?

```
.ui-collapsible {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  -ms-transition: all 1s;
  -o-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

Not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery Mobile's collapsible elements are shown and hidden by toggling `display: none` on the div of the collapsible content. As far as I know, all major browsers disable CSS transitions when the `display` property is changed.

An alternative would be overriding the default CSS of jQuery Mobile to always use `display: block` for the collapsible content div, and then transition on the `height` or `opacity` property (depending on whether or not the content needs to be "removed" from the layout).

I've created this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fcvps/1/), to demonstrate the transition using the `opacity` property. It is really just a matter of using the following CSS rules:

```
.ui-collapsible-content {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -ms-transition: all 1s;
    -o-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
    opacity: 1;
}
.ui-collapsible-content-collapsed {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0
}
```

Transition using the `height` property is a little trickier as the content div has no set height. This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fcvps/3/) does the trick (also see CSS below), but it requires setting a height on the content div. You can change the height to `auto`, but then the slide down effect doesn't look quite right in my opinion. Perhaps someone else knows a better method.

```
.ui-collapsible-content {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -ms-transition: all 1s;
    -o-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
    height: 2em; /* or auto */
    overflow: hidden;
}
.ui-collapsible-content-collapsed {
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    padding: 0 16px;
}
```

Comment: How to make content slide down and slide up instead of fade in and fade out?

Comment: I added a second example that transitions on height, but it requires a predefined height, e.g. 2em. It will also work with a height of 'auto', but the slide down effect doesn't look quite right in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

```
.ui-collapsible-content {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -ms-transition: all 1s;
    -o-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
    opacity: 1;
}
.ui-collapsible-content-collapsed {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0
}
```

Comment: How to make content slide down and slide up instead of fade in and fade out?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to Creating custom **CSS-based transitions**:-

[Refer This](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-customtransitions.html)